# How to programmatically determine default email account/address in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, email

On an iOS device, once can configure multiple email accounts. In the Settings app, a user can pick a default email account (Mail->Mail:DefaultAccount). This default account is the "from" address when sending email via MFMailComposeViewController.

Is there any Apple-approved way to programmatically detect either the name of the default account or the email address being used as "from"?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Were you able to read email acc info inside the iOS app?

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe it is possible in iOS to obtain the user's email address.

A similar question was asked here:
[Get default user email in iOS Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758431/get-default-user-email-in-ios-device)

Comment: I could use either the email address OR the default account name.