# Programmatically access configure email Id of iPhone

Tags: ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programmatically determine default email account/address in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646018/how-to-programmatically-determine-default-email-account-address-in-ios)

Is there any public API to fetch programatically all email Id  which is configure on user's iPhone like gmail, yahoo , hotmail etc ?  I don't want to ask  user to fill the email Id in  text field in my app at the time of registration instead user can choose his email from dropdown .
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no public API to get a user's email address or any information about any email accounts they have setup. You have to ask the user.