# How to send mail from JavaScript in phone Gap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Guys i'm working on phone gap and i want to add functionality of sending mail. What i want is when i send mail it fetch the already log in mail id from device and how to add mailto id. Provide me some reference or some codes so that i can utilize those resources.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS try this https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/EmailComposer, refer this link to know about retrieving login mail in iOS [Get default user email in iOS Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758431/get-default-user-email-in-ios-device)