# Getting user email during iOS InApp purchase

Tags: email, in-app-purchase, user-accounts, itunes-store

Is there anyway in iOS to retrieve the current user email (I suppose it would be the iTunes profile email) after a InApp purchase attempt (either successful or not)?

Comment: I had the same problem and dont know if its possible or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with iOS public SDK (i.e. SDK 7 at this time).

cf. [this question for another way to get the user's email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758431/get-default-user-email-in-ios-device/20075649).